# How can I incorporate modulo arithmetic to allow my tiles to skip over other tiles?

Tags: python, loops, pygame, modulo, tiles-game

```py
def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT, NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT, SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Slide Puzzle')
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', BASICFONTSIZE)

    # Store the option buttons and their rectangles in OPTIONS.
    RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT = makeText('Reset',    TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 90)
    NEW_SURF,   NEW_RECT   = makeText('New Game', TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 60)
    SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT = makeText('Solve',    TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)

    mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80)
    SOLVEDBOARD = getStartingBoard() # a solved board is the same as the board in a start state.
    allMoves = [] # list of moves made from the solved configuration

    while True: # main game loop
        slideTo = None # the direction, if any, a tile should slide
        msg = 'Click tile or press arrow keys to slide.' # contains the message to show in the upper left corner.
        if mainBoard == SOLVEDBOARD:
            msg = 'Solved!'

        drawBoard(mainBoard, msg)

        checkForQuit()
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                spotx, spoty = getSpotClicked(mainBoard, event.pos[0], event.pos[1])

                if (spotx, spoty) == (None, None):
                    # check if the user clicked on an option button
                    if RESET_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        resetAnimation(mainBoard, allMoves) # clicked on Reset button
                        allMoves = []
                    elif NEW_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80) # clicked on New Game button
                        allMoves = []
                    elif SOLVE_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        resetAnimation(mainBoard, solutionSeq + allMoves) # clicked on Solve button
                        allMoves = []
                else:
                    # check if the clicked tile was next to the blank spot

                    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(mainBoard)
                    if spotx == blankx + 1 and spoty == blanky:
                        slideTo = LEFT
                    elif spotx == blankx - 1 and spoty == blanky:
                        slideTo = RIGHT
                    elif spotx == blankx and spoty == blanky + 1:
                        slideTo = UP
                    elif spotx == blankx and spoty == blanky - 1:
                        slideTo = DOWN

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                # check if the user pressed a key to slide a tile
                if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a) and isValidMove(mainBoard , LEFT):
                    slideTo = LEFT
                elif event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d) and isValidMove(mainBoard , RIGHT):
                    slideTo = RIGHT
                elif event.key in (K_UP, K_w) and isValidMove(mainBoard , UP):
                    slideTo = UP
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN, K_s) and isValidMove(mainBoard , DOWN):
                    slideTo = DOWN

        if slideTo:
            slideAnimation(mainBoard, slideTo, 'Click tile or press arrow keys to slide.', 8) # show slide on screen
            makeMove(mainBoard, slideTo)
            allMoves.append(slideTo) # record the slide
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def checkForQuit():
    for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT): # get all the QUIT events
        terminate() # terminate if any QUIT events are present
    for event in pygame.event.get(KEYUP): # get all the KEYUP events
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate() # terminate if the KEYUP event was for the Esc key
        pygame.event.post(event) # put the other KEYUP event objects back


def getStartingBoard():
    # Return a board data structure with tiles in the solved state.
    # For example, if BOARDWIDTH and BOARDHEIGHT are both 3, this function
    # returns [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, BLANK]]
    counter = 1
    board = []
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        column = []
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            column.append(counter)
            counter += BOARDWIDTH
        board.append(column)
        counter -= BOARDWIDTH * (BOARDHEIGHT - 1) + BOARDWIDTH - 1

    board[BOARDWIDTH-1][BOARDHEIGHT-1] = BLANK
    return board


def getBlankPosition(board):
    # Return the x and y of board coordinates of the blank space.
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            if board[x][y] == BLANK:
                return (x, y)


def makeMove(board, move):
    # This function does not check if the move is valid.
    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)

    if move == UP:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx][blanky + 1] = board[blankx][blanky + 1], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == DOWN:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx][blanky - 1] = board[blankx][blanky - 1], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == LEFT:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx + 1][blanky] = board[blankx + 1][blanky], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == RIGHT:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx - 1][blanky] = board[blankx - 1][blanky], board[blankx][blanky]


def isValidMove(board, move):
    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)
    return (move == UP and blanky != len(board[0]) - 1) or \
           (move == DOWN and blanky != 0) or \
           (move == LEFT and blankx != len(board) - 1) or \
           (move == RIGHT and blankx != 0)


def getRandomMove(board, lastMove=None):
    # start with a full list of all four moves
    validMoves = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]

    # remove moves from the list as they are disqualified
    if lastMove == UP or not isValidMove(board, DOWN):
        validMoves.remove(DOWN)
    if lastMove == DOWN or not isValidMove(board, UP):
        validMoves.remove(UP)
    if lastMove == LEFT or not isValidMove(board, RIGHT):
        validMoves.remove(RIGHT)
    if lastMove == RIGHT or not isValidMove(board, LEFT):
        validMoves.remove(LEFT)

    # return a random move from the list of remaining moves
    return random.choice(validMoves)


def getLeftTopOfTile(tileX, tileY):
    left = XMARGIN + (tileX * TILESIZE) + (tileX - 1)
    top = YMARGIN + (tileY * TILESIZE) + (tileY - 1)
    return (left, top)


def getSpotClicked(board, x, y):
    # from the x & y pixel coordinates, get the x & y board coordinates
    for tileX in range(len(board)):
        for tileY in range(len(board[0])):
            left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(tileX, tileY)
            tileRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            if tileRect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (tileX, tileY)
    return (None, None)
```

I would like to allow it where my tiles can jump to other side of the board if it is available. If a tile is on the left, and an empty slot is on the right; I want to make it where if it where it will jump over and skip the tiles using modulo arithmetic.

I have tried to incorporate modulo arithmetic looping but im not sure where to fully put it in. I have tried it on the makeMove function but I was presented with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the modulo to check for "wrap around" blank slots.

Based on the comments in the function `getStartingBoard()`:

```
# returns [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, BLANK]]
```

It seems a board is a two dimensional list, where the cell at `(x,y)` would be `board[y][x]`.

So say we have a board of some `BOARD_WIDTH` by `BOARD_HEIGHT`, given a cell's co-ordinates (`x`,`y`), we need to find a list of the neighbouring cells where it's "BLANK" - which we will assume is the number zero.

So first we build a list of all neighbouring cells.  At this stage we don't care if they go outside the board.  It just adds the cells, top-left, top-centre, ..., bottom-right.  Obviously we don't include the actual referenced cell in this.

Then we go through the cell-list, correcting any that are outside the bounds of the board.  The fix is to simply add the dimension to the value.  Thus if our `x` has become `-1`, we can add the BOARD_WIDTH, so it becomes `BOARD_WIDTH-1`, which is the right-side column number.  Similarly if `x` equals BOARD_WIDTH, subtracting wraps this back to zero.  We do the same thing for the y-value.

As a final step, we run through the list of cells, finding the BLANK ones, and added them to a list for returning.

```
def getBlankCellsAround( board, x, y, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT ):
    """ Return a list of BLANK cells around the board position (x,y) """
    # Default cells around x,y
    cell_list = [ (x-1, y-1), (x, y-1), (x+1, y-1), \
                  (x-1, y),             (x+1, y),   \ 
                  (x-1, y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1, y+1) ]

    # Correct any cells that are off the edge so they wrap-around
    blanks_list = []
    for cell in cell_list:
        cx, cy = cell
        if ( cx < 0 ):
            cx += BOARD_WIDTH
        elif ( cx >= BOARD_WIDTH ):
            cx -= BOARD_WIDTH    
        if ( cy < 0 ):
            cy += BOARD_HEIGHT
        elif ( cy >= BOARD_HEIGHT ):
            cy -= BOARD_HEIGHT

        if ( board[cy][cx] == 0 ):   # if it's blank, copy it to output
            blanks_list.append( ( cx, cy ) )

    # return the list of blank cells (which might be zero-length)
    return blanks_list
```